# Как заставить работать вложенный ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, android-viewpager

У меня есть родительский viewPager2 который переключает фрагменты при свайпе. Внутри одного фрагмента есть вложенный ViewPage2 для слайда картинок. Но работает только родительский viewPager. Как заставить работать оба. Для первой версии ViewPager есть решение в интернете, но оно не подходит для ViewPager2

Answer (score 0):

Короче, решения из коробки этой проблемы нет (по крайней мере, пока). Нашел решение в гугловских доках.
Добавляем этот класс:

```
class NestedScrollableHost : FrameLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    private var touchSlop = 0
    private var initialX = 0f
    private var initialY = 0f
    private val parentViewPager: ViewPager2?
        get() {
            var v: View? = parent as? View
            while (v != null && v !is ViewPager2) {
                v = v.parent as? View
            }
            return v as? ViewPager2
        }

    private val child: View? get() = if (childCount > 0) getChildAt(0) else null

    init {
        touchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop
    }

    private fun canChildScroll(orientation: Int, delta: Float): Boolean {
        val direction = -delta.sign.toInt()
        return when (orientation) {
            0 -> child?.canScrollHorizontally(direction) ?: false
            1 -> child?.canScrollVertically(direction) ?: false
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        handleInterceptTouchEvent(e)
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e)
    }

    private fun handleInterceptTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent) {
        val orientation = parentViewPager?.orientation ?: return

        // Early return if child can't scroll in same direction as parent
        if (!canChildScroll(orientation, -1f) && !canChildScroll(orientation, 1f)) {
            return
        }

        if (e.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            initialX = e.x
            initialY = e.y
            parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        } else if (e.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            val dx = e.x - initialX
            val dy = e.y - initialY
            val isVpHorizontal = orientation == ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL

            // assuming ViewPager2 touch-slop is 2x touch-slop of child
            val scaledDx = dx.absoluteValue * if (isVpHorizontal) .5f else 1f
            val scaledDy = dy.absoluteValue * if (isVpHorizontal) 1f else .5f

            if (scaledDx > touchSlop || scaledDy > touchSlop) {
                if (isVpHorizontal == (scaledDy > scaledDx)) {
                    // Gesture is perpendicular, allow all parents to intercept
                    parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
                } else {
                    // Gesture is parallel, query child if movement in that direction is possible
                    if (canChildScroll(orientation, if (isVpHorizontal) dx else dy)) {
                        // Child can scroll, disallow all parents to intercept
                        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                    } else {
                        // Child cannot scroll, allow all parents to intercept
                        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И оборачиваем наш вложеный ViewPager в этот контейнер:

```
<com.shamilov.payda.ui.helpers.NestedScrollableHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</com.shamilov.payda.ui.helpers.NestedScrollableHost>
```